# Как задать отступ изображению в excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

Имеется такой код:

```
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(os.path.join(path, "photos", list_images[i]))
    img.width = 400
    img.height = 400
    sheet.add_image(img, 'A%d'%(i+1))
    sheet.row_dimensions[i+1].height = img.height * 0.75
    sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = img.width * 0.143
```

Как задать отступ сверху и слева на 1 пиксель, что бы изображение не перекрывало сетку экселя